# Unit test fails saying could not find 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight' assembly

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, mstest

Unit test(MS test framework) runs successfully in the system in which it is written but fails in other systems and throwing the below error::

> "Unit Test Adapter threw exception:  Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight,
>   Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.."

'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight' is already added as reference in my project but still the test cases are failing.Am I missing any other references?
Need help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: What is the other system?

Comment: Both the computers are of same configuration - Windows Server 2008 R2 standard,64 bit OS.

Comment: And is that system has visual studio installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is resolved by adding the dll to GAC using `gacutil -i <path of the dll>`.

e.g.:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Testing>gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight.dll
```

Comment: for *VS21013 on win7 x64*  
  
    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\" 
  
    gacutil.exe -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Toolkit\dec11\Testing\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.‌​UnitTesting.Silverlight.dll"

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with above answer, even OP has marked it, please check this thread: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q286983
**But neither our Silverlight assemblies nor framework ones should be added to the GAC.**
So uninstall the assembly you had installed in GAC.
I hope this can be helpful.